# fluxible rehydrate method is not being triggered on route change

Tags: javascript, fluxible

Will `fluxible` `app.rehydrate` be called on every router change?

When is `app.rehydrate` getting called in the whole fluxible application lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

Rehydrate is called only first time when application is started on a client side (browser) to restore data that was used to render on a server. That is it's purpose, there is nothing to rehydrate when you navigating the app.